# How can i change Icon in app Bar by value?

Tags: flutter, dart, logging

I'm new in Flutter.
In the application I am creating, I have the app bar with a login button icon. I wish I could change the login icon based on a value of a global variable, which allows me to understand if I am logged in or not.

I've tried via an if-else but can't. This is my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        title: Text('HOME'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person_outline,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              tooltip: 'Login/Registrati',
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
              })
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: are you try ternary condition ?

Comment: Have you stored any value in the session when the user logged in?

Comment: i used a boolean variables. if the login was successful I change the value in true, otherwise The value is false

Comment: @Benn you can check my answer

Comment: Can you please add the if-else condition you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I used `isLogin` boolean value for checked user login or not and on this basis, I change the `icon` as well as the `onPressed` function

```
 Container(
                child: isLogin == true
                    ? IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.person_outline,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        tooltip: 'Login/Registration',
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
                        })
                    : IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.exit_to_app,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        tooltip: 'Logout/ExitToApp',
                        onPressed: () {
                          // Your Logout method
                        }),
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator for loading widgets based on conditions.

```
IconButton(icon: ifValue==true? Icon(Icons.YourIcon): Icon(Your Second Icon))
```

You can change style on the basis of conditions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used `isLogin` as `bool` to check if user is logged in or not. Depending on it widget will change its icons and onPressed funciton,

```
 AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    title: Text('HOME'),
    actions: [
      isLogin ? IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.person_outline,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
           //Your medthod if user is logged in
          }) : IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.logout,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
           //Your medthod if user is logged out
          })
    ],
  ),
```